# How to get push notification payload inside local notification

Tags: push-notification, swift3, apple-push-notifications, ios10, uilocalnotification

[image: I want to achive this from local notification][image: WhatsApp Incoming Video Call]I am developing a webRTC (video calling) application in ios. I am receiving a APNS push notification from server,whenever user receive a incoming video call on the device.

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "Incoming video call from - Bob",
        "badge" : 1,
        "sound" : "bingbong.mp3",
        "userdata" : {JSON}
    }
}
```

How can I store it inside Local Notification?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I achieved it using apple Voip push service and Pushkit Framework , it allow me to handle my payload inside Local notification ,while the app is in background or forcefully terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store data in local push notification then you can add the data like this,

```
let interval = TimeInterval(1)
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval, repeats: false)
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Incoming video call from - Bob"
content.body = "Your body"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: "CustomSound.mp3")
content.badge = "Your badge number"
content.userInfo = ["userData": YOUR_USER_DATA from remote]
let req = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "localPushNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.add(req, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```